# How to access Elements of a java class in c++ using JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I've been given a task to print the values of elements in a Java Class in C++ using JNI. But I don't know where to start.

Here is the C++ code:

```
#include "sample1.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_sample_methodCall
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj, jobject obj)
{ 

  jclass cls = env->FindClass("sample1");
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the Java Code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class sample1
{
    String name="XYZ";
    public native void methodCall(sample1 obj);
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
      sample1 s = new sample1();
      s.methodCall(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post code snippets instead of images of code.

Comment: *I dont know where to start.* -- You start by going to reputable sites or get books that explain how to do this.  You certainly won't start by asking us how to do this -- JNI programming in general cannot be explained simply within a question / answer site such as StackOverflow.

Comment: It will require some tweaking. Accessing fields of Java class from JNI is not quite like siting on cloud nine (mostly due to esoteric syntax). All you have to do is to get IDs of the fields inside class and read them using JNI's methods. After you get the feeling of how to do it, it's not a big deal: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-020/

Comment: From the programmer's perspective, interacting with Java objects through JNI is essentially the same the as doing it in Java using reflection, except that the names of the functions are a bit different (e.g. `FindClass` instead of `Class.forName`, etc). So if you're familiar with reflection in Java, JNI shouldn't be a problem. Also, read [the JNI function reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ code

```
#include "sample2.h"  

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_sample2_callMethod(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobject jobj) 

{

    jclass jcls;  

    jfieldID fid, fname;  

    jint i;  

    jstring str;  

    jcls = env->GetObjectClass(jobj);  

    fid = env->GetFieldID(jcls,"val","I");  

    fname = env->GetFieldID(jcls,"name","Ljava/lang/String;");  

    str = (jstring)env->GetObjectField(jobj, fname);  

    const char *nameUCpp = env->GetStringUTFChars(str, 0);  

    i = env->GetIntField(jobj, fid);  

    printf("%d %s", i, nameUCpp);  

    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(str, nameUCpp);  

}  

int main()  

{  

    return 0;  

}
```

Java code

```
import java.io.*;

public class sample2

{  

    public native void callMethod(sample2 s);  

    int val=7;  

    String name="Siva";  

    public static void main(String args[])  

    {  

        System.loadLibrary("sample2");  

        sample2 s = new sample2();  
        s.callMethod(s);  
    }  

}
```